# How to write customize test cases in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing

Can I white my own customize stassert statements for test cases in objective c?

Comment: You can assert true, then insert whatever logic inside.

Comment: Is there any example for this .

Comment: What kind of logic so complex that you want to customize?

Comment: I have isDownloaded flag in database . When flag is Y then it should not download resource when flag is N then it should download the resource . I have test case named:-(void)testshouldNotDownLoadWhenisDownloadedFlagIsYes

Comment: You need to somehow "return" (or store) some sort of value that indicates whether the download happens or not. I'm thinking another way along the line of exposing the internal variable conditionally with macro for testing.

Comment: yaah i already thought about that but my function getResource already returning the path of resource. so how can i return the downloading status from same function?

Comment: You can set some variable that is only available during testing (using `#define` and `#ifdef`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing integration testing, or testing that involves interaction between several different components, I understand that it is hard to confirm that certain behavior happened or not - since the behavior might be hidden or not even recorded in the main code.

One solution is to write code that to record behavior or expose internal state to the testing unit, and use `#ifdef` to surround such block of code.

You can add the preprocessor macro to the build setting of the app target (not the test target) for the Debug mode. This can be a potential source of confusion, though.

Comment: I have found solution though i didnt want to implement it . I defined a flag in app delegate class and setting that flag in class. And i am checking the same flag in unit test class. This is working but is it good practice?

Comment: @VXtreme: I would not want the flag to be compiled into the final product, so I surround it with the `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can write them.
Read about GHUnit, OCUnit and OCMock unit testing.
read this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

Answer (score 0):

The assert statements are just macros, so there is no reason why you couldn't write your own. Check out `SenTestCase_Macros.h` to see how they are implemented. If it's something you use all the time, writing your own custom assertions could be worthwhile, but often it's easier just to write your own logic and do an STAssertTrue like nhahtdh recommends.

If I was getting started with iOS unit testing right now, I would go straight for [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi). It's a much nicer syntax than SenTestingKit, and writing your own custom high level matchers is much easier (writing a concise little class, not an indecipherable macro).